# Is it possible to set a trigger that is only fired when a specific column value change and depend on what the value is it calls different functions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have a table with a column that will receive one of three pre-seted values, would be possile to set a trigger to check on each insert/update on the table, the value and calls a different functions according to the value?

ex:

column X

value => 'foo' calls function fooFunction()

value => 'bar' calls function barFunction()

Comment: Yes, more or less.

Comment: Using the ```WHEN (condition)``` of the ```CREATE TRIGGER``` would even allow you to fire different triggers directly. But you can also use it to fire one trigger and deciding inside the trigger with an ```IF/ELSE``` construct which function should be executed. Documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `WHEN (condition)` of the `CREATE TRIGGER` would even allow you to fire different triggers directly. But you can also use it to fire one trigger and deciding inside the trigger with an `IF/ELSE` construct which function should be executed. Possible SQL code:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger_upd BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.value = 'foo' AND OLD.value IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.value)
EXECUTE FUNCTION foo_function();

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger_ins BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.value = 'foo')
EXECUTE FUNCTION foo_function();
```

Documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html

**EDIT:** You cannot combine `INSERT` and `UPDATE` trigger in one `CREATE TRIGGER` since we want to check the `OLD` record in case of an update but it cannot be used with an insert.

Comment: Regarding your edit, in an insert the `OLD` is just `NULL`, and you can check for that. Or inside the function itself, check the [`TG_OP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)